# WebRTC - It is possible to get specified media device info - e.g. speakers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, mediadevices

I want to play specified sound by speakers on my site. I already get all user devices by mediaDevices.getUserMedia like in this demo https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/.

The point is get speakers not e.g. headset etc. DeviceInfo object has 4 properties:

deviceId - some GUID

group ID - some other GUID

kind - filtered by 'audiooutput'

label - name

There is any chance to have 100% of  sure that we get speakers?

I already filtered to ignore default :

```
function findSpeakers(audioOutputList){

    let defaultDevice = audioOutputList.filter(device => {

        if(device.deviceId == "default" && device.kind == "audiooutput"){

            return true;

        }else{

            return false;

        }

    })



    let audioOutputsWithoutDefault = audioOutputList.filter(device =>{

        if(device.label.indexOf(defaultDevice[0].label.replace('Default - ','')) < 1 && device.kind == "audiooutput"){

            return true;

        }else{

            return false;

        }

    })

    console.log(audioOutputsWithoutDefault);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

u r not ignoring 'default', u r using 'default' only

'default' is the best thing, which is selected at the os level, and will play sound at the default audio output, which is what is needed in most cases right.

I don't think thats possible to get the exact output device before hand. Although you can select any :)

1. Different browsers will return different, similar, results for:

   navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function (mediaDevices){
       console.log("mediaDevices: ", mediaDevices);
   });
2. It is possible to select mic, camera default through site settings, in chrome, but not audio output.

But u can give a list of possible audio output and select from there like:
[webrtc](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/)